# Call the onTapGesture method on a View that has child views that have onTapGestures without overriding

Tags: swiftui

**I want to** be able to add a `onTapGesture{}` to a View without overriding the `onTapGesture{}`s that may be part of the that view already.

**Example:**

```
struct NotAPieceOfLettuce: View {
    var body: some View{
      Text("what am I?").onTapGesture{print("I am not a piece of lettuce")}
     }
}

struct Banana: View {
    var body: some View{
       NotAPieceOfLettuce().onTapGesture{print("just a banana, not lettuce")}
    }
}
```

The code above will actually print `just a banana, not lettuce` on tap, although I want it to print `I am not a piece of lettuce` and also `just a banana, not lettuce`...

**I have tried** `.simultaneousGesture()` but the program output is no different than what it is with the example code above.

Thank you for reading, WiseEye YT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simultaneous gesture should be specified at both sides, like

```
struct NotAPieceOfLettuce: View {
    var body: some View{
      Text("what am I?")
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{print("I am not a piece of lettuce")})
     }
}

struct Banana: View {
    var body: some View{
       NotAPieceOfLettuce()
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{print("just a banana, not lettuce")})
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: Amazing, yeah, I only used simultaneous gesture on the child previously... by the way, you answer like 80% of all Swift questions... You are a legend!

Comment: Just need it on the one that does not launch otherwise. (So the parent in this case, since the child is the more targeted one and is preferred.)

Comment: @IiroAlhonen you are right, although I can't accept both... any reason why I should accept yours instead? Is your approach safer? better? more performant?

Comment: @WiseEye it's clearer for what default behavior is being overridden. I haven't tested the performance in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `.simultaneousGesture` on the gesture that does not get launched otherwise. In this case that would be the parent container.

```swift
// Child component
struct NotAPieceOfLettuce: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("what am I?")
            .onTapGesture{print("I am not a piece of lettuce")}
    }
}

// Parent component, whos `onTapGesture` doesn't get called.
struct Banana: View {
    var body: some View{
        NotAPieceOfLettuce()
            .simultaneousGesture(
                TapGesture()
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        print("just a banana, not lettuce")
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Paul Hudson article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-two-gestures-recognize-at-the-same-time-using-simultaneousgesture